# how to stop cmake to rebuild static libraries if they already present

Tags: build, cmake, static-libraries

I have following project structure

```
CmakeLists.txt
    src/main.cpp
      A/CMakeLists.txt
      A/test.cpp
      B/CMakeLists.txt
      B/other.cpp
   libs/
```

The build configuration is written in a way that the
sub-directories are compiled as static libraries (stored into libs) and then they are used to produce final binary.

Now suppose I transfer this project to my bud, with only CMakeLists.txt, source-files and static libraries in libs.

When compiling the project, he/she have to recompile again all the source files, despite the libraries are already there.

Is there any way to tell cmake to re-use pre-build static libraries ??

Excerpt from top cmakelist.txt .

```
add_subdirectory (${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/A)
add_subdirectory (${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/B)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libs)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libs)

add_executable(myBinary ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp )
add_dependencies(myBinary A B)
target_link_libraries (myBinary A B)
```

Subdirectory cmakelist.txt .

```
project (A)
file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")
add_library (A STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

Comment: When you build a library with CMake, it is built in the **build tree**, and a *build tree* is not supposed to be transferable to other machine. So you may transfer only a *source tree*, not a *build* one. If you want your colleague to use the libraries which have already built, put created library files into the *source tree* (and adjust `CMakeLists.txt` to use prebuilt libraries).

Comment: If you want to transfer the results of a build around, it is suggested to install them and transfer the install tree around. Here, headers and libraries should be installed. You'll also likely want a package configuration file if the library is going to be used from another CMake project.

Comment: @Tsyvarev ._put created library files into the source tree (and adjust CMakeLists.txt to use prebuilt libraries_ , that was exactly my question. How should I do that?  suppose I moved libraries to src/libs. what then ?

Comment: If you ask about linking pre-built libraries, then see that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library.